# Mark edges as loop

Tags: edges, selection-tools

I've imported an SVG and, unfortunately, Blender doesn't recognize the loops. This makes selection much harder—I have to select each edge individually rather than use loop selection.

Is there a way to mark a group of edges as a loop, so that I don't have to select each of the edges every time?

Comment: It's possible to save selection to vertex groups as is shown in the answer, though note that selecting edge loop with Alt+Left click works only if it is formed with quads.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Vertex Groups.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html)

[image]

You might also use [Select Next Element](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/selecting.html#select-next-previous) to select the edges faster if they are in a loop. Just select the first 2 edges and then use the short code <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: Wouldn't that be (1) - (3) - (2) - "Assign"...?!

Comment: That image comes from the blender doc, they specify the (1)-(2)-(3) there. *See first link*

Comment: Plus should be pressed first (to add the group), then choose it to define which groups to add to. Or press Ctrl+G with vertices selected. The context in the manual is slightly different, they explain there that list is empty on (2), so it's not a step to do

Comment: Edited the example image for clarity.